# difference between varchar and int when doing max()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a technical difference between these two, when table.column is a varchar or int? When would the results **not** be the same? I tried a few examples of digit values (e.g. 1, '1', etc.) and results are the same.

```
 -- table.column is int:
 select
    MAX(table.column) as m

 -- table.column is varchar:
 select
   MAX(CAST(table.column as int)) as m
```

Comment: try with 2 or 3 digits value like `99` and `100`

Comment: The real question here is why would you use `varchar` to store `int` values in the first place?

Comment: The `max` aggregating function follows the same sort rules as the `order by` clause.
Because both queries use `max` on an `int` value, the result would be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the result are same, because after casting both of the values are converted into `int` type.

If any string which is actually `int` type converted into `int` shows no difference over there. But if you have any string of any other type and you're converting that string into `int` type it gives error.

```
declare @str nvarchar(100)
set @str = 'sdsfd fdf fd dfsf'

select cast(@str as int)
```

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3486
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'sdsfd fdf fd dfsf' to data type int.

For strings that can be converted to integers there is no difference in aggregate functions.

```
declare @dd table ( id varchar(max), id2 int)
insert into @dd ( id, id2 )
values ( '1', 1 )
, ( '99', 99 )
, ( '52', 52 )

select max(id2) as col, max(cast(id as int)) as col1 from @dd


Result
------------------
col    col1 
99     99
```

Thanks for @Zohar for reminding.

Although it is better to use `Try_cast` for your type conversion in SQL Server 2012 and above version.

Comment: Which is why it's better to use `try_cast` instead of `cast`, unless you're working with an unsupported version (pre 2012).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a technical difference between these two

If there's an index on `column`, the server can use it to cheaply compute the `MAX` for the "`column` is an `int`" version of your query. Not for the other.

> When would the results not be the same?

There shouldn't be a difference in the *result*<sup>1</sup> but as I say above, there may be a considerable difference in the *amount of work the server has to do* to compute the result. Even without the index, all of those conversions require additional code to run.

---

<sup>1</sup>Assuming all of the strings are convertible to `int`s.